# What do you call the distance driven on a vehicle?

Tags: terminology

In the US (and I suppose other places where distances are still measured in miles) the term is *mileage*. But what about the rest of the world? Is there an SI term for mileage? Or is mileage still the term used in English speaking countries – but without the implication of the units of the distance.

Comment: The word *mileage* is used regardless of whether the person uses the imperial system. I've heard people use *kilometrage* as well, it's just not as popular. However this question is probably more fit for english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, in South Africa we often use the word "mileage" when referring to the odometer reading even when we use the Metric System.

Answer (score 3):

For the Netherlands:

> What's the milage on the timing belt?

I never heard a dedicated word for this. Just 'How much has the car driven?' [since it left the factory]'. Or 'How much has the car driven since replacing the belt?'

Personally I tend to use mileage. But I do tend to mix rather more foreign words into my language than is the norm. Kilometrage would also be understood but I never heard that actually used.

As for the answers which read the question as fuel usage, that would have been easy to answer: 'verbruik'.  ('Usage')  E.g. 'Het verbruik is 1:18'.

How that is used might be a fun question on it own for this site. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one answer.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070914034648AAElZe9) keeping in mind that Australia also speaks "Queen's English". It really is up to whoever is saying it at that moment. I've seen them say "miles per gallon of petrol" on Top Gear. Miles and gallons are both US measurements and "petrol" is the European term for gas... And that a BBC TV show! Lol!

So really it doesn't matter officially and to my understanding there is no current SI term for it.

### Additional Resource

[Here is another thread on the same topic.](http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=248297)

Comment: Petrol (British) = Gas / Gasoline (US) = Benzin / Benzyn / Benzīns / Бензин etc (all the rest of the world :D ) 1 US Gallon = 0.832674 Imperial gallons.

Comment: And they use MPH in England, IIRC. At least the last time I was over there, the speed limit was 70MPH on the highway (or whatever they call it there, lol). May have changed since I was over there last in 2002, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 lol!

Comment: Miles FTW!!!!!!

Comment: Yep, we use miles and gallons in the UK. Proper gallons too - 4.54 litres ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kilometers. Look around classifieds posts from other countries.

Fun note: Some countries will also list hours of usage for some off-road capable vehicles.

Comment: Ah, not the distance it self, but how would you ask the question "for how much distance has this vehicle been driven" – like "what's the milage on the timing belt?" Or what kind of milage do you get on a set of tires?

Comment: Well yeah, kilometers. How many KM on this engine? How many since the last timing belt? And so on. :)

Comment: "How many miles on the clock?"

Answer (score 0):

In countries that don't use the metric state gas mileage in miles per gallon. In metric countries they use liters per 100 kilometers written as L/100 Km. Similarly  speed limits in metric countries are given in kilometer per hour written as Km/h.

Imperial Gallons are 1.25 times larger than U.S Gallons. There are 4.54 liters in a Imperial Gallon and about 3.6 Liters in a U.S Gallon.

1.609 Km = 1 Mile.

One thing I like about the metric system while driving it seems faster.
60 MPH = 96 KM/h
100 MPH = 160 Km/h

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @ tlhIngan : Kilometrage may be technically correct. However the phrase for fuel economy in metric countries is either kilometers per liter or liters per 100 Km. The only people who use the term  mileage in a metric country are over 40+ years of age.

Comment: The content of your post is factually correct, but it still does not answer the question. The OP was asking about distance driven, not fuel economy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the technical term you are looking for is known as the Odometer Reading.

The [Odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer) refers to the indicator in the car which displays the total distance that vehicle has traveled.